# Event to bind to for displaying frequently changing data from service

Tags: angular, events

I am creating an Angular 4 component which will show some data provided by an angular 4 service.  The data changes regularly, so I want the component to check for new data every time it is displayed (not just get data once upon construction).

What is the right event to bind to?  ngoninit seems to run only once upon creation of the component, so assigning the result of the service function to a member variable in NgOnInit doesn't seem right.  I believe the component is created once upon starting/loading the app.

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: How often are you expecting to update the data? On an interval? On user interaction?

Comment: "data changes regularly" how does you data change ? can you provide some code snippet ?

Comment: data is fetched from a REST service.  (Hopefully I expressed the question correctly).  I just want to ensure it's not cached on app start and always shows the same data...

Answer (score 0):

`ngOnInit` is called everytime the component is instantiated, that means it runs everytime the component is "added" to the DOM.

For example if you add an `ngIf` on the component and its input is changing `false` to `true`.

So if you want to load data everytime the component is "displayed", just make sure it is removed from the DOM when it is not visible. Like:

```
<my-component *ngIf="isVisible"></my-component>
```

Another way is to have an named `router-outlet` which displays the component upon a specific url. ([example](https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets))

You can find more information about [lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) in the docs.